# Persisting Logs in Managed Packages

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, dml, debug-logs

What is the best practice to persist logs from apex classes, batch jobs, and controllers? We are still in the development stage so we haven't considered LMA. We tried to store it in a custom object. But with this approach, we are not able to persist logs from controllers and constructors as DML operations are not allowed.

Comment: Inserting into a custom object doesn't work in general because those inserts are rolled back whenever the overall transaction is rolled back. See Mohith's answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building Enterprise ready apps for Enterprise edition and above, use platform event feature

Platform events can be published in apex and subscribed via a simple apex trigger.

Fire a platform event on error and write a trigger to subscribe and store the error in a custom object.

This is an asynchronous action as well so would have less impact on CPU.